# reducing loops by using Numpy(Arnoldi method)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, loops

I am asking to implement Arnoldi method with one loop.[image]

I tried

```
def arnoldi(A, b, k):
    """
    For a matrix A, apply k iterations of the Arnoldi algorithm,
    using b as the first basis vector.

    :return Q: an mx(k+1) dimensional numpy array containing the orthonormal basis
    :return H: a (k+1)xk dimensional numpy array containing the upper \
    Hessenberg matrix
    """
    m = len(A)
    Q = np.zeros((m, k + 1), dtype = complex)
    H = np.zeros((k + 1, k), dtype = complex)
    Q[ :, 0] = b / norm(b)
    for i in range(k):
        v = A @ Q[ :, i]
        for j in range(i + 1):
            H[j, i] = np.conj(Q[ :, j]) @ v
            v -=  H[j, i] * Q[ :, j]
        H[i+1, i] = norm(v)
        Q[: , i+1] = v / norm(v)
    return Q, H
```

It gives the correct result. But it consists 2 loops. I wonder how to reduce it to one loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: Since `Q` is changed in the `i` loop, that can't be replaced.  But I suspect the `j` loop can be replaced.  For example `H[:,i] = np.conj(Q[???] @ v)`.  I'd have to identify the shape of `v` and `Q` to get the modified `@` correct.  And the next line looks like a `np.sum` of the `j` dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Your code with thinking-through-it notes:

```
def arnoldi(A, b, k):
    """
    For a matrix A, apply k iterations of the Arnoldi algorithm,
    using b as the first basis vector.

    :return Q: an mx(k+1) dimensional numpy array containing the orthonormal basis
    :return H: a (k+1)xk dimensional numpy array containing the upper \
    Hessenberg matrix
    """
    m = len(A)
```

What's the shape of `A`?  (m,?)

```
    Q = np.zeros((m, k + 1), dtype = complex)   #(m,k1)
    H = np.zeros((k + 1, k), dtype = complex)   #(k1,k)

    Q[ :, 0] = b / norm(b)       # b must be (m,) shape
    for i in range(k):
        v = A @ Q[ :, i]
```

`A@Q[:,i]` works if `A` is (m,) or (m,m) since `Q[:,i]` is (m,).
`v` will be scalar or (m,)

`vk=A@Q` could be done outside the `i` loop, with `v=vk[:,i]` inside the loop.

```
        for j in range(i + 1):
            H[j, i] = np.conj(Q[ :, j]) @ v
            v -=  H[j, i] * Q[ :, j]
```

`H[j,i]` is a single element slot.  `Q[:,j]` is (m,), `@v` then requires `v` be (m,).  And `A` must then be (m,m).

`H[:i+1,i] = v@np.conj(Q[:,:i+1])` should work, `(m,)@(m,i+1)=>(i+1,)

`H[j,i]*Q[:,j]` is scalar times (m,) => (m,), which works with `v-=`.

`H[:i+1,i] * Q[:,:i+1]` will be (i+1,)*(m,i+1)=>(m,i+1); sum on axis 1

So the `j` loop could be replaced with:

```
   H[:i+1,i] = v@np.conj(Q[:,:i+1])
   v -= np.sum(H[:i+1,i] * Q[:,:i+1])`
```

The rest is outside the `j` loop; but in the `i` one:

```
        H[i+1, i] = norm(v)
        Q[: , i+1] = v / norm(v)
    return Q, H
```

Without array samples, I'm not going to test these changes.  I could very well have made mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I modified the function as you suggested and tested it. I still get assertion errors. I also tried " v -=  Q[:, : i+1] @ H[i, :i+1]". It still doesn't work but gives different result.

Comment: Hi, the code works after I change "v -= np.sum(H[:i+1,i] * Q[:,:i+1])" to "v -= Q[:, : i+1] @ H[:i+1, I]". I am not sure why because I thought they are the same